# How to debug .net 500 that not catched by UseDeveloperExceptionPage

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker-compose, microservices

I have a .net service that runs in a container.
When I run it I have a very wired issue.

Assuming I have the link `HTTP//:www.a.com/page`.

The first attempt to call `HTTP//:www.a.com/page` succeeds, the second failed with 500, the third succeeded again, and so on.

In the output window, I can find: `Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.Private.Uri.dll` and `Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException'`.

Initially, I thought that all the odd requests succeeded, but then more random patterns started to appear.
I tried to wait a few random seconds between attempts but it did not solve the issue.
Basically, some of the requests succeeded and some did not (again they are all exactly the same requests).

I added UseDeveloperExceptionPage. but it didn't catch anything, I added a BP on my first middleware, the requests that succeed break in it, the 500 never reach that point.

This led me to think that something is rung with Kerstel himself.

I returning 404 on the path, maybe Kerstel has caching mechanized that return automatically 500 if I repeat asking for a 404 path under x minutes?

The question is, how can I debug it? Where is the source of this bug?

This is the current setup of the `Program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();



var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    
}

// Should be the first middleware
app.UseHealthChecks("/HealthCheck");

app.UseRouting();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.Map("/{**catch-all}", async httpContext =>
    {
        // return 200 if we are healthy here
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return;
    });
});

Console.WriteLine("Test Version 6");

app.Run();


public partial class Program { } // so you can reference it from tests
```

-- edit --

When I use localhost (swagger) to communicate with .net, there is no error, only when I use it through the docker naming (using a regular browser request) there is an error, here are the traces:

Trace of swagger request (return 404 as expected):

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
    Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50182/category_1a1a1a1a%2Fproduct_2a2a2a2a%2Fid_1123467.product?sig=EEF7952F7B823B6981A797AAE429DF - -
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[2]
    All hosts are allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[3]
    The request path  does not match the path filter
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
    1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/category_1a1a1a1a%2Fproduct_2a2a2a2a%2Fid_1123467.product?sig=EEF7952F7B823B6981A797AAE429DF'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1005]
    Endpoint '/{**catch-all}' with route pattern '/{**catch-all}' is valid for the request path '/category_1a1a1a1a%2Fproduct_2a2a2a2a%2Fid_1123467.product?sig=EEF7952F7B823B6981A797AAE429DF'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[1]
    Request matched endpoint '/{**catch-all}'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
    Executing endpoint '/{**catch-all}'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
    Executed endpoint '/{**catch-all}'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[9]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOE" completed keep alive response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
    Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50182/category_1a1a1a1a%2Fproduct_2a2a2a2a%2Fid_1123467.product?sig=EEF7952F7B823B6981A797AAE429DF - - - 404 0 - 3126.3906ms
The thread 0xf12 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf0f has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '.NET ThreadPool Worker' (0xb2) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '.NET ThreadPool Worker' (0xbf) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '.NET ThreadPool Worker' (0xc1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '.NET ThreadPool Worker' (0xb8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf14 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf15 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Trace of browser request (return 404 as expected but with wired failures):

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOF" accepted.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOF" started.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
    Request starting HTTP/1.0 GET http://proxy_backend/category_1a1a1a1a/product_2a2a2a2a/id_1123467.product?sig=EEF7952F7B823B6981A797AAE429DF - -
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[2]
    All hosts are allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[3]
    The request path  does not match the path filter
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
    1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/category_1a1a1a1a/product_2a2a2a2a/id_1123467.product'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1005]
    Endpoint '/{**catch-all}' with route pattern '/{**catch-all}' is valid for the request path '/category_1a1a1a1a/product_2a2a2a2a/id_1123467.product'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[1]
    Request matched endpoint '/{**catch-all}'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
    Executing endpoint '/{**catch-all}'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
    Executed endpoint '/{**catch-all}'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
    Request finished HTTP/1.0 GET http://proxy_backend/category_1a1a1a1a/product_2a2a2a2a/id_1123467.product?sig=EEF7952F7B823B6981A797AAE429DF - - - 404 0 - 1959.3089ms
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[10]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOF" disconnecting.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOF" stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOF" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
    Connection id "0HMJER5USLLOF" received FIN.
```

Then the trace of the next browser request (return 500 - failure):

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.Private.Uri.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

It looks like everything is normal when I access .net using `http://localhost:50182/` but when I access it from `http://proxy_backend` (the docker name) only then I get the issues

Comment: Add proper exception handling. The developer exception page doesn't *catch* unhandled exceptions, it only displays them. These will still propagate. That exception page is only available in development environments too, and even there, only visible to localhost. It's your application's job to catch and log exceptions.

Comment: What is the *full* exception text? Log the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This includes the actual location where the exception occured, any inner exceptions and most importantly, the stack trace that shows the chain of functions that led to the exception. Somewhere in there you'll find the call that caused the `UriFormatException`. Perhaps you're concatenating `http://proxy_backend` with a relative URL *without* including a trailing slash?

Comment: I can't catch it, I tried: `options.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandlingFilter());` , `app.UseExceptionHandler`, adding handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`, adding handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: I even tried to `try catch` around `app.Run();`, still didn't catch anything, just seeing the exception in the output window

Comment: Catching means adding `try/catch` to your own *action* code, not letting the exception propagate all the way to the top.

Comment: The error isn't from my code, looks like the error come from `Kestrel ` itself

Comment: `Kestrel` returning the 500 before the request hit my first line of my action code

Comment: If I try many times (~every 4 times) to end requests I catch `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.` in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`